# wrapping printf and still take parameters

Tags: f#

```
/// Colored printf
let cprintf c fmt = 
    Printf.kprintf 
        (fun s -> 
            let old = System.Console.ForegroundColor 
            try 
              System.Console.ForegroundColor <- c;
              System.Console.Write s
            finally
              System.Console.ForegroundColor <- old) 
        fmt

// Colored printfn
let cprintfn c fmt = 
    cprintf c fmt
    printfn ""
```

With [the above stolen code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/10/01/f-zen.aspx),

```
cprintfn ConsoleColor.Yellow "This works"
```

but

```
cprintfn ConsoleColor.Yellow "This %s" "doesn't"
(cprintfn ConsoleColor.Yellow) "still %s" "doesn't"
(cprintfn ConsoleColor.Yellow "still %s") "doesn't"
cprintfn ConsoleColor.Yellow ("still %s" "doesn't")
```

I know this has to do with `Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>` vs simple strings but even specifying a type for `fmt` as in `cprintf c (fmt:Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>)`, I can't get the kprintf part to work.  I read a bunch of answers related to logging, but I still can't figure it out.  Is a cprintf that takes format parameters possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your `cprintf` function is perfectly fine and you can use it with variable number of arguments. The problem is only with the `cprintfn` function:

```
cprintf System.ConsoleColor.Red "%s %d" "hi" 42
```

The problem is that when you're defining a function that uses formatting string, you always need to use partial application. That is your function has to be of the form:

```
let myprintf fmt = 
  <whatever>
  otherprintf <whatever> fmt
```

The important thing is that `otherprintf <whatever> fmt` has to be the last part of the body and it has to take `fmt` as the last argument. This way, when `otherprintf` needs more arguments (as specified by `fmt`) these are automatically propagated and become arguments of `myprintf`.

This means that defining `cprintfn` in terms of `cprintf` is actually quite tricky. But you can always define a helper function that is a bit more powerful and lets you do both:

```
let cprintfWith endl c fmt = 
    Printf.kprintf 
        (fun s -> 
            let old = System.Console.ForegroundColor 
            try 
              System.Console.ForegroundColor <- c;
              System.Console.Write (s + endl)
            finally
              System.Console.ForegroundColor <- old) 
        fmt

let cprintf c fmt = cprintfWith "" c fmt
let cprintfn c fmt = cprintfWith "\n" c fmt
```

Comment: Awesome!  But I think you meant to say `let cprintf c = cprintfWith "" c` and `let cprintfn c = cprintfWith "\n" c`.  Thanks!

Comment: ... otherwise they aren't partially applied